# Android Skia remote surface

Tags: android, vnc, skia

Hi I was researching the possibility to transport the "not rendered" rendering calls to a second screen from Android. While researching I found out that Skia is behind the Surfacefinger, and the Canvas.draw() method. So my question is now, what would be the best interception point to branch off the calls in order to use them for a second screen / machine. The second device mut not be a pure replay device, but can be another Android device.

First I used VNC for that concept, but quickly found out that it badly performs, due to the double buffering effect, it is also possible to manipulate the android code in a sense that it omits the double buffering, but it is still of interest to actually use the pre rendered calles on a second, maybe scaled device.

Thanks